Search does not work in Angular when the field is inside an object
I want {{item.registration.patientId}} to be searchable instead of {{item.mainId}}. See JSON file and notice that patientID is an object inside registration.
The search works when I search for mainId but it doesn't when I replace mainID with patientId in the TS file. Also, if I replace mainId with sequence, the search works too. It does not work on any fields which is inside {{item.registration.xxx}}.
I also tried replace mainId with registration.patientId in the TS file inside the function getDetail() but that doesn't work either. It continues showing all the 10 items.
This is on my patient.component.html file:
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID" #myInput>
    <button (click)="getDetail(myInput.value)" type="button">Search</button>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of bills; let count = index">
    <div>{{count +1}}</div>
    <div>{{item.registration?.patientId}}</div>
    <div>{{item.mainId}}</div>
    <div>{{item.registration?.firstName}}</div>
    <div>{{item.registration?.mobile}}</div>
</div>

This is on my patient.component.ts file:
export class ViewBillsComponent implements OnInit {
  public bills = [] as Billing[];
  public componentQuery = new HttpParams();
  public paginationData = {} as Pagination;
  constructor(
    private coreService: CoreService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBills();
  }

  getBills(){
    this.coreService.getBillings(this.componentQuery).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.bills = res.data;
        this.paginationData = res
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
  }

  getDetail(searchId= ''){
    console.log(searchId)
    this.componentQuery = this.componentQuery.set('mainId', searchId);
    console.log(this.componentQuery)
    this.getBills();
  }

  paginateTo(page:number){
    this.componentQuery = this.componentQuery.set('page', page)
    this.getBills()
  }
}

Notice that {{item.registration.patientId}} is an object while mainId is outside of the {{registration.xx}}. This is the JSON file:
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "66ad004d952855f99c907d7c",
            "registration": {
                "_id": "66ad001f952855f99c907d1e",
                "firstName": "Test5001",
                "lastName": "Leone",
                "mobile": 3987298279,
                "createdAt": "2024-08-02T15:49:51.848Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-08-02T15:49:51.848Z",
                "sequence": 21,
                "patientId": "PT21",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "amount": 0,
            "date": "2024-08-02T15:50:00.000Z",
            "createdAt": "2024-08-02T15:50:37.934Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-08-02T15:50:37.934Z",
            "sequence": 45,
            "mainId": "ID45",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "66ad003c952855f99c907d50",
            "registration": {
                "_id": "66ad003c952855f99c907d46",
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Wick",
                "mobile": 847900919,
                "createdAt": "2024-08-02T15:50:20.043Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-08-02T15:50:20.043Z",
                "sequence": 22,
                "patientId": "PT22",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "amount": 500,
            "date": "2024-08-02T15:49:00.000Z",
            "createdAt": "2024-08-02T15:50:20.121Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-08-02T15:50:20.121Z",
            "sequence": 44,
            "mainId": "ID44",
            "__v": 0
        },
    ]
}

Here is my core.services.ts file:
getBillings(params?: HttpParams) {
    return this.httpClient.get(
      `${environment.backend_base_url}billing`,
      {params}
    );
  }

This is my interfaces file:
export interface patient {
    _id: string;
    registration?:any;
    sequence?: number;
    mainId?:string;
    date?:any;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    is_active?:boolean;
}


seems like you're passing that as queryParams (this.componentQuery.set('mainId', searchId);) , so coreService.getBillings is expecting mainID there.  I'd suggest a pulldown for SearchType, and you might pass that along with a SearchTerm to your coreService.getBillings method.

Please let me know how can I pulldown for SearchType. I have updated my question and added the interfaces and core.service.ts file

In general, things only work a certain way when you program them to work in that way. It seems you've not programmed the search to search anything beyond the mainId field. Considering it is the server-side API that handles the searching, I would sat that we'd need to see that code as well to help find the problem. The error is not due to Angular; it's completely between the API and the consumer of the API.

The search is being done in the backend and has no front end code involved, please update the backend code, so that it queries the nested field registration.patientId along with the current fields, this will solve your issue.
This is a pure backend issue, the API is performing the filtering here.

This does not answer the question. The question should be closed pending the arrival of the backend code, not answered with non-answers.

@HereticMonkey I have previous knowledge of this question Since I answer OP previous questions, so I am answering it based on that.

Then include that extra information in the answer here. Remember, answers are not for the OP alone, but for everyone who has the same question in the future.

@HereticMonkey OP will contact backend team and fix the issue :) I never saw the backend code,  ill delete the answer once OP has seen this :) no worries!
